# a:hover background-postition problem

Tags: css, hover, css-sprites, background-position

For some reason, I am not entirely sure why, but the following is not working. The background position simply stays the same on hover. I cannot figure out why. I could do it another way, but I would like to try and get to the bottom of why it does not work.

```
#nav a:link, #nav a:visited {
    background:url(../img/nav-sprite.png) no-repeat;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:200px;
    padding:10px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:solid 1px red;
}

    #nav a#home {
        background-position:-10px 0px;
        width:30px;
    }
    #nav a#about-us {
        background-position:-85px 0px;
        width:45px;
    }

#nav a:hover    {
    background-position:1px -15px;
}
```

Does anybody know what could be causing this?

Thanks in advance!

Ryan

Comment: Does it make a difference which browser you try it on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ID selectors have priority over the pseudo-class selectors..

thus the `#` rule will not be overriden by a `:` rule..

either use the !important directive

```
#nav a:hover    {
    background-position:1px -15px!important;
}
```

or make the rule more specific

```
#nav a#home:hover, #nav a#about-us:hover    {
    background-position:1px -15px;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `! important` as a CSS hammer! x_x

Comment: Do use `!important` as a CSS hammer!

Answer (score 3):

`#nav a#home` and `#nav a#about-us` have higher specificity than `#nav a:hover` (id > pseudo-class), so the latter is never applied. `#nav a#home:hover` and `#nav a#about-us:hover` would work here.

See [the cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).

Comment: Ahh yes, i totally understand now. I should have known that! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#nav a#home:hover, #nav a#about-us:hover    {
    background-position:1px -15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not relevant anymore but if someone will get here so there is one more option:

Change the Ids to Classes. 
Intead of `<a id="home">`
use `<a class="home">`.
Now change your styles from `a#home` to `a.home` and it will work.

Full code:

```
<div id="nav">
    <a href="#" class="home">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="about-us">About Us</a>
</div>

<style>
        #nav a:link, #nav a:visited
        {
            background: url('smile-icon.jpg') no-repeat;
            display: block;
            float: left;
            height: 140px;
            padding: 10px;
            text-indent: -9999px;
            border: solid 1px red;
        }

        #nav a.home
        {
            background-position: -10px 0px;
            width: 30px;
        }

        #nav a.about-us
        {
            background-position: -85px 0px;
            width: 45px;
        }

        #nav a:hover
        {
            background-position: 1px -15px;
        }
    </style>
```